# Updating Ajax function asynchronously

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am trying to update data asynchronously. Currently, if I refresh the page, only then I see new data in the console log.

My ajax script:

```
$.ajax({
         url: '{% url 'messages' %}',
         datatype: 'json',
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(body) {
             console.log(body)
                }
         });
```

My view:

```
    inbox = Messages.objects.filter(receiver=user).order_by('-timestamp')

    serialized_inbox = serializers.serialize('json', inbox)

    return HttpResponse(serialized_inbox, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Try inspecting the actual request for clues in browser dev tools network tab. Check that it is made, status, response body etc. Also is there a form involved here? Unfortunately there really isn't much debugging detail here to work from. Having to refresh page to make ajax work is not a common issue

Comment: When the page is loaded, the ajax function is called and I get the console log. But after loading, the ajax is not looking for new data. I am new to js and ajax, so I might be missing something to make that function asynchronous @charlietfl

Comment: Oh I get it now. Sounded like the first request didn't work at all without reloading the page. If you want it to make multiple requests you would need to use an interval timer like `setInterval` to call the same thing each time.